# How to make my image background responsive in any size

Tags: html, css

Hello guys can anyone help me with this, When I tried viewing my design on a smaller screen the image background is not look alike on the big screen can anyone help me how to achieve it? the first image is the background I've been using.

```css
.container-flex.lgn-customize {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    min-height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    /* background-image: url(/materials/media/icons/login-icon/login_bg.png); */
    background-position: bottom center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}


.nk .container-flex {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: initial;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.container-flex.lgn-customize::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 49%;
    transform: translate(100%, -50%);
    right: 0%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    background-image: url(/materials/media/icons/login-icon/test222111.png);
    /* background-position: bottom center; */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    /* transition: 1s ease-in-out; */
    /* border-radius: 50%; */
    z-index: 6;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-flex lgn-customize">
        
        
</div>
```

[image: actual image i use in css]

[image: Large Screen]

[image: Smaller Screen]

Comment: as you can see the 3rd image is cut when I view it on small screen/monitor

Comment: so you want to keep keep the blue part as it even when you resize the screen?

if you resize the screen after a certain width your content will move to fit in screen  so you will have to readjust your background

Comment: that's what happened now when I adjusted the screen the bg image also adjusted. So meaning I should add a media query to adjust the design on a smaller screen?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the background-size property to contain. It tells the browser that the background image scales trying to fit the content area, without loosing its aspect ratio.

```html
<style>
.container-flex.lgn-customize {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    min-height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image:  url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1604085572504-a392ddf0d86a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8b3JhbmdlJTIwZmxvd2VyfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&w=1000&q=80');
    background-position: bottom center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;
}


.nk .container-flex {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: initial;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.container-flex.lgn-customize::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 49%;
    transform: translate(100%, -50%);
    right: 0%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    background-image: url(/materials/media/icons/login-icon/test222111.png);
    /* background-position: bottom center; */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    /* transition: 1s ease-in-out; */
    /* border-radius: 50%; */
    z-index: 6;
}
</style>
<div class="container-flex lgn-customize">
        
        
</div>
```